# Set all values in a column equal to the first non-null value over a window in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, postgresql-9.6

Take this table as an example:

```
+----+------------+------+
| id |    date    | flag |
+----+------------+------+
| A  | 01/01/2020 |    0 |
| A  | 01/02/2020 |    0 |
| A  | 01/03/2020 |    0 |
| A  | 01/04/2020 |    1 |
| A  | 01/05/2020 |    1 |
| B  | 01/01/2020 |    0 |
| B  | 01/02/2020 |    1 |
| B  | 01/03/2020 |    1 |
| B  | 01/04/2020 |    1 |
| B  | 01/05/2020 |    1 |
+----+------------+------+
```

There is some flag that is either set to 0 or 1. I want to create a new column called `day_flagged` that will contain the date that the flag first became a 1. For example, for `id` A, that would be `01/04/2020`. For `id` B, that would be `01/02/2020`.

This is what I currently have:

```
SELECT x.id, 
       x.date, 
       ( CASE 
           WHEN prev_flag = 0 
                AND next_flag = 1 
                AND x.flag = 1 THEN 1 
           ELSE NULL 
         END ) AS flagged 
FROM   (SELECT id, 
               date, 
               flag, 
               Lag(flag) 
                 OVER ( 
                   partition BY id 
                   ORDER BY date ASC) AS prev_flag, 
               Lead(flag) 
                 OVER ( 
                   partition BY id 
                   ORDER BY date ASC) AS next_flag 
        FROM   tableA) AS x;
```

The result of that is this:

```
+----+------------+---------+
| id |    date    | flagged |
+----+------------+---------+
| A  | 01/01/2020 | null    |
| A  | 01/02/2020 | null    |
| A  | 01/03/2020 | null    |
| A  | 01/04/2020 | 1       |
| A  | 01/05/2020 | null    |
| B  | 01/01/2020 | null    |
| B  | 01/02/2020 | 1       |
| B  | 01/03/2020 | null    |
| B  | 01/04/2020 | null    |
| B  | 01/05/2020 | null    |
+----+------------+---------+
```

I'm able to identify when the value of `flag` for each `id` first changed from 0 to 1 and store that in `flagged`. How can I take the `date` value corresponding to the rows where `flagged` is 1, and insert that date into every row of the partition as `day_flagged`?

Desired outcome:

```
+----+------------+------+-------------+
| id |    date    | flag | day_flagged |
+----+------------+------+-------------+
| A  | 01/01/2020 |    0 | 01/04/2020  |
| A  | 01/02/2020 |    0 | 01/04/2020  |
| A  | 01/03/2020 |    0 | 01/04/2020  |
| A  | 01/04/2020 |    1 | 01/04/2020  |
| A  | 01/05/2020 |    1 | 01/04/2020  |
| B  | 01/01/2020 |    0 | 01/02/2020  |
| B  | 01/02/2020 |    1 | 01/02/2020  |
| B  | 01/03/2020 |    1 | 01/02/2020  |
| B  | 01/04/2020 |    1 | 01/02/2020  |
| B  | 01/05/2020 |    1 | 01/02/2020  |
+----+------------+------+-------------+
```

DB Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wJsTnvNkYELHqLjHRx1pie/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want the date of the first `1` for each `id`.

If so, it seems like a conditional window `min()` would fit your need:

```
select
    t.*,
    min(date) filter(where flag = 1) over(partition by id) day_flagged
from tableA t
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wJsTnvNkYELHqLjHRx1pie/5)**:

```
| id  | date       | flag | day_flagged |
| --- | ---------- | ---- | ----------- |
| A   | 01/01/2020 | 0    | 01/04/2020  |
| A   | 01/02/2020 | 0    | 01/04/2020  |
| A   | 01/03/2020 | 0    | 01/04/2020  |
| A   | 01/04/2020 | 1    | 01/04/2020  |
| A   | 01/05/2020 | 1    | 01/04/2020  |
| B   | 01/01/2020 | 0    | 01/02/2020  |
| B   | 01/02/2020 | 1    | 01/02/2020  |
| B   | 01/03/2020 | 1    | 01/02/2020  |
| B   | 01/04/2020 | 1    | 01/02/2020  |
| B   | 01/05/2020 | 1    | 01/02/2020  |
```